# Eclipse like Java development environment in Android tablets

Tags: android, eclipse, ide

Can anyone tell whether Android OS for tablet would support Eclipse like Java development environment? Please help....Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check AIDE app on Google PlayStore.

Comment: Eclipse supports Java development for Android OS

Comment: @Mel I think the question is whether one _develop_ on the tablet rather than using a desktop to do so. Raghav, can you confirm whether this was indeed the question?

Comment: @curioustechizen you got it right.